# switch case performance and probability

Tags: c, performance, switch-statement

I am writing a c string parser and i want it as fast as possible. I know that in the stream  certain occurance of characters could (will) be more probable than others, i could write an if else to specify the order and fix my concern, but i prefer to do it in a switch case witch is more readable for me. I know the compiler perform optimizations that could affect the order of the effective cmp operation's, so i wonder if there is some special flags that force the compiler to do his optimization but respecting the order specified in the C source code.

Comment: Write clean correct code first then profile it and optimize the hotspots. You may be worrying about something that won't even be a blip in the profiler.

Comment: If the values are small integers, `switch/case` is often translated into a jump table, which doesn't require any comparisons so order is not an issue.

Comment: If the code parsed is sufficiently large, then the branch should be often correctly *predicted* by modern CPUs unless you have really a lot of branches. Conditions are very cheap when they are correctly predicted. Jump tables are generally not faster than a miss predicted condition, so they only worth it if they are a lot of cases. AFAIK, the order of condition only have a small impact on performance, unless the tests are expensive (which should not be the case if you can use a switch).

Comment: You can't use C strings in `switch case` so I believe it is an XY problem. That stream of data will come from somewhere